# How to reuse the same code in several Display Templates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, displayfor

I have 2 Display Templates that have the same code on a few lines.

Is there is a way to move a common code to another file and reference that file in both templates?

For example:

Display Template #1 and # 2 have the following common code:

```
IFormatProvider formatProvider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string formattedCurrency = null;

if (formatProvider.ToString().Equals("en-US"))
{
    formattedCurrency = (@Model < 0 ? @Model.ToString("C", formatProvider) : (@Model).ToString("C", formatProvider));
}
else
{
    formattedCurrency = (@Model < 0 ? "- " + @Math.Abs(@Model).ToString("C", formatProvider) : (@Model).ToString("C", formatProvider));
}
```

How can I move it to a separate file and reference that from both templates?

Comment: What about:
 - Moving that `formattedCurrency` logic to a `viewModel` common function?
- Creating a child template helper `formattedCurrencyHelper` that has that piece of code and include it in each DisplayTemplate1 and DisplayTemplate2?

Just ideas...

Comment: I'm relatively new to MVC, so just trying to learn it. Is that possible create the same kind of View and pass model to it and just call it somehow from these 2 templates?

Answer (score 0):

So my first option was to have the `formattedCurrency` prop as a common function:

```
public class LocalizedViewModel {
   private IFormatProvider formatProvider;
   public float Currency { get; set; }
   public string FormattedCurrency () {
     if (formatProvider.ToString().Equals("en-US"))
     {
         return  (this.Currency < 0 ? this.Currency.ToString("C", formatProvider) : (this.Currency).ToString("C", formatProvider));
     }
     else
     {
         return (this.Currency < 0 ? "- " + Math.Abs(this.Currency).ToString("C", formatProvider) : (this.Currency).ToString("C", formatProvider));
     }
   }
  public LocalizedViewModel () {
    formatProvider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  }
}
```

And then inherit both ViewModels from this base model

```
public class MyModel1: LocalizedViewModel {
   public MyModel1() : base() {
   }
}

public class MyModel2: LocalizedViewModel {
   public MyModel2() : base() {
   }
}
```

Then every time you create an object you have access to this prop:

```
var myModel = new Model1();
var myModel2 = new Model2();
myModel.Currency = 100;
myModel2.Currency = 200;
```

Now both viewmodels will have the formattedCurrency to display on any view, without the need on any extra view logic. Hope this helps and could be a viable option to you.

```
myModel.FormattedCurrency();
myModel2.FormattedCurrency();
```

And render that property on any template. Again this is an alternative solution to achieve the same results. But with a different approach.

Regards